# Spring boot @RedisHash creates multiple keys instead of one

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I am using `spring-data-redis` to add and retrieve data fro Redis. But once the data is written to the redis, I can see multiple keys instead of one. On expiration only 1 key is getting removed and rest of the keys are still present in Redis.

```
@RedisHash( timeToLive = 60, value="vault_token" )
@Data
public class VaultTokenModel {

    private Integer id;

    private String token;
}
```

To save,

```
VaultTokenModel vaultTokenModel = new VaultTokenModel();
                vaultTokenModel.setId(1);
                vaultTokenModel.setToken(getVaultToken());
                VaultTokenModel savedToken = vaultTokenRepository.save(vaultTokenModel);
                return savedToken.getToken();
```

But when I open the `redis-cli` and run `KEYS *`, I can see,

```
1) "vault_token:1"
2) "com.highpeak.tlp.attributemanager.db.model.VaultTokenModel:1:phantom"
3) "vault_token:1:phantom"
4) "com.highpeak.tlp.attributemanager.db.model.VaultTokenModel"
5) "vault_token"
```

And after the set `timeToLive`, if I run the same command again, I can see,

```
1) "com.highpeak.tlp.attributemanager.db.model.VaultTokenModel:1:phantom"
2) "vault_token:1:phantom"
3) "com.highpeak.tlp.attributemanager.db.model.VaultTokenModel"
4) "vault_token"
```

What are these additional keys and why are they getting created with full package name and with a random unique identifier `phantom`.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

These multiple keys are maintained by Spring Data Redis, just some meta info.
If you're curious, you can issue

```
type [whatever-key]
```

in the redis command, to find the type of the key, then issue a corresponding get command.
For example, if

```
type vault_token
```

returns the result as  hash,
then you use

```
hgetall vault_token
```

to look at what's inside.

The phantom thing you see is just some info cached by Spring Data Redis and will be deleted after a while. For more info, check [delete key/value from redis - phantom key not deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467965/delete-key-value-from-redis-phantom-key-not-deleted)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: @Naanavanalla - If you think this answer has helped you, kindly consider accepting it. Thanks!