# Phantom Key - Spring Data Redis - Goal/Best Practices

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I'm working with Spring Data Redis and I'm a little bit confused about the utility of phantom key. Below some questions about that :

- What's the goal of Phantom Key for Spring Data Redis?
- When should I save it or not? What are the impacts?
- Is there best practices on this subject?

Thank advance for your feedback.

Comment: As we can see on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467965/delete-key-value-from-redis-phantom-key-not-deleted. Spring Data Redis manages phantom key to manage secondary indexes along with other functionalities.

Comment: As we can see, it's possible to disable phantom key here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations by @EnableKeyspaceEvents(shadowCopy = OFF)

Answer (score 0):

> When the expiration is set to a positive value, the corresponding
> EXPIRE command is run. In addition to persisting the original, a
> phantom copy is persisted in Redis and set to expire five minutes
> after the original one. This is done to enable the Repository support
> to publish RedisKeyExpiredEvent, holding the expired value in Spring’s
> ApplicationEventPublisher whenever a key expires, even though the
> original values have already been removed. Expiry events are received
> on all connected applications that use Spring Data Redis repositories.
>
> By default, the key expiry listener is disabled when initializing the
> application. The startup mode can be adjusted in
> @EnableRedisRepositories or RedisKeyValueAdapter to start the listener
> with the application or upon the first insert of an entity with a TTL.
> See EnableKeyspaceEvents for possible values.
>
> The RedisKeyExpiredEvent holds a copy of the expired domain object as
> well as the key.

For more information see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories.expirations